# How to assign a value to a column for a subset of dataframe based on a condition in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,4,0,0],
[1,5,1,0],
[2,6,0,0],
[3,7,1,0]], columns=['index', 'A', 'class', 'label'])
```

df:

| index | A | class | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 5 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 6 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 7 | 1 | 0 |

I want to change the label to 1, if the mean of A column of rows with class 0 is bigger than the mean of all data in column A?

How to do this in a few line of code?

I tried this but didn't work:

```
if df[df['class'] == 0]['A'].mean() > df['A'].mean():
   df[df['class']]['lable'] = 1
```

Comment: so in your example the condition doesn't fulfill, hence there is no change in expected output? you should add a solution which has a change in expected output in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following, [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) `'class'`, get [`groupby.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) of each group of `'A'`, check whether greater than `df['A'].mean()`, and [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) that `boolean` series [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)`(int)` to `df['class']` and assign to `df['label']`:

```
>>> df['label'] = df['class'].map(
        df.groupby('class')['A'].mean() > df['A'].mean()
    ).astype(int)

>>> df

   index  A  class  label
0      0  4      0      0
1      1  5      1      1
2      2  6      0      0
3      3  7      1      1
```

Since you are checking only for `class` == 0, you need to add another `boolean mask` on `df['class']`:

```
>>> df['label'] = (df['class'].map(
        df.groupby('class')['A'].mean() > df['A'].mean()
        ) & (~df['class'].astype(bool))
    ).astype(int)
   index  A  class  label
0      0  4      0      0
1      1  5      1      0   # because (5+7)/2 < (4+5+6+7)/4
2      2  6      0      0
3      3  7      1      0   # because (5+7)/2 < (4+5+6+7)/4
```

So even if your code has worked, you will not know it, because the conditions do not get fulfilled.

Comment: Actually, I am checking for all 'class' values. But your explanation has deepen my knowledge. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, if the condition you mentioned is fullfilled, than the labels of all rows changes to 1 right? in that case what you did es correct but you missed something, the code should look like this:

```
if df[df['class'] == 0]['A'].mean() > df['A'].mean:
   df['label'] = 1
```

This should work.
What you did does not work because when you use df[df['class']], you are only selecting the 'class' column of the DataFrame, so the 'label' column you want to modify is not called

Comment: No actually. If the condition for a subset of data is met, the label should change to 1 for that subset of data!